# Designing hierarchy tables

Tags: sql-server

Lets say that I have to store the following information in my database,
[image]

Now my database tables will be designed and structured like this,
[image]

In a later date, if I had to add another sub category level how will I be able to achieve this without having to change the database structure at all?

I have heard of defining the columns as row data in a table and using pivots to extract the details later on...Is that the proper way to achieve this?

Can someone please enlighten me or guide me in the proper direction? Thanks in advance...

:)

Comment: Use a table with hierarchy which holds parent child relation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be difficult to add more columns to your table when new levels are to be generated. The best way is to use a `Hierarchy table` to maintain `Parent-Child relationship`.

**Table : `Items`**

```
 x----x------------------x------------x
 | ID |      Items       | CategoryId |
 |----x------------------x------------x
 | 1  |   Pepsi          |     3      |
 | 2  |   Coke           |     3      |
 | 3  |   Wine           |     4      |
 | 4  |   Beer           |     4      |     
 | 5  |   Meals          |     2      |
 | 6  |   Fried Rice     |     2      |
 | 7  |   Black Forest   |     7      |
 | 8  |   XMas Cake      |     7      |
 | 9  |   Pinapple Juice |     8      |
 | 10 |   Apple Juice    |     8      |
 x----x------------------x------------x
```

**Table : `Category`**

[image]

In category table, you can add categories to `n` levels. In `Items` table, you can store the lowest level category. For example, take the case of `Pepsi` - its `categoryId` is 3. In Category table, you can find its parent using `JOIN`s and find parent's parents using Hierarchy queries.

In `Category` table, the categories with `ParentId` is null(that is with no parentId) will be the `MainCategory` and the other items with `ParentId` will be under `SubCategory`.

**EDIT :**

Any how you need to alter the tables, because as per your current schema, you cannot add column to the first table because the number of Sub category may keep on changing. Even if you create a table as per **Rhys Jones** answer, you have to join two tables with string. The problem in joining with string is that, when there is a requirement to change the `Sub category` or `Main category` name, you have to change in every table which you be fall to trouble in future and is not a good database design. So I suggest you to follow the below pattern.

Here is the query that get the parents for child items.

```
DECLARE @ITEM VARCHAR(30) = 'Black Forest'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Finds the original parent for an ITEM ie, Black Forest 
    SELECT I.ID,I.ITEMS,C.CategoryId,C.Category,ParentId,0 [LEVEL]
    FROM #ITEMS I
    JOIN #Category C ON I.CategoryId=C.CategoryId   
    WHERE ITEMS = @ITEM

    UNION ALL

    -- Now it finds the parents with hierarchy level for ITEM  
    -- ie, Black Forest. This is called Recursive query, which works like loop
    SELECT I.ID,I.ITEMS,C.CategoryId,C.Category,C.ParentId,[LEVEL] + 1
    FROM CTE I
    JOIN #Category C ON C.CategoryId=I.ParentId 
)
-- Here we keep a column to show header for pivoting ie, CATEGORY0,CATEGORY1 etc
-- and keep these records in a temporary table #NEWTABLE
SELECT ID,ITEMS,CATEGORYID,CATEGORY,PARENTID,
'CATEGORY'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMS ORDER BY [LEVEL] DESC)-1 AS VARCHAR(4)) COLS,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMS ORDER BY [LEVEL] DESC)-1 [LEVEL] 
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ITEMS,[LEVEL]
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Here is the result from the above query

[image]

**Explanation**

- `Black Forest` comes under `Cake`.
- `Cake` comes under `Bakery`.
- `Bakery` comes under `Food`.

Like this you can create children or parent for any number of levels. Now if you want to add a parent to `Food` and `Beverage`, for eg, `Food Industry`, just add `Food Industry` to `Category` table and keep `Food Industry's` Id as `ParentId` for `Food` and `Beverage`. Thats all.

Now if you want do pivoting, you can follow the below procedures.

**1. Get values from column to show those values as column in pivot**

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COLS + ']', '[' + COLS + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT COLS,[LEVEL] FROM #NEWTABLE) PV 
               ORDER BY [LEVEL]
```

**2. Now use the below PIVOT query**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT ITEMS, CATEGORY, COLS  
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CATEGORY)
                 FOR COLS IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY ITEMS;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04250/2) to view result

You will get the below result after the pivot

[image]

**NOTE**

1. If you want all the records irrespective of an item, remove the `WHERE` clause inside `CTE`. [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04250/4) to view result.
2. Now I have provided order of columns in pivot table as `DESC` ie, its shows top-level parent.....Item's parent. If you want to show Item's parent first followed be next level and top-level parent at last, you can change `DESC` inside the `ROW_NUMBER()` to `ASC`. [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04250/6) to view result.

Comment: Do you need to show as pivoted report? Like, an item, its main category and its sub categories...like that? @Gayanee Wijayasekara

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. :) Yes I need to have all the details of the categories so that the I can later filter the details and find records based on the selection criteria. @ Sarath Avanavu

Comment: K. So u need queries to find an item, then by its parent and parent's parents etc? @Gayanee Wijayasekara

Comment: "K. So u need queries to find an item, then by its parent and parent's parents etc?" Yes

Comment: It would be great if you can share the queries with me. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Sure. I will update with queries and proper ways of working around this. @Gayanee Wijayasekara

Comment: I have updated. Please check now. Feel free to ask for any changes @Gayanee Wijayasekara

Comment: Hiii...Many many thanks for the update. This has practically saved my life. :) I'm trying to design my database according to the way you explained and was halfway through designing my data extraction queries. (You see for explaining my concern I used the beverage/food example, but what I really need to develop is a scenario related to apparel industry).This answer that you have provided is really helpful and clear. I'm sorry that I didn't get back to you earlier. I wanted to finish designing my database before contacting you. :) @Sarath Avanavu

Answer (score 3):

According to your schema there's no relationship between 'main category' and 'sub category' but your sample data suggests there would be a relationship, i.e. Alcohol IS A Beverage etc. This sounds like a hierarchy of categories, in which case you could you a single self-referencing Category table instead;

```
create table dbo.Category (
    CategoryID int not null constraint PK_Category primary key clustered (CategoryID),
    ParentCategoryID int not null,
    CategoryName varchar(100) not null
)

alter table dbo.Category add constraint FK_Category_Category foreign key(ParentCategoryID) references dbo.Category (CategoryID)

insert dbo.Category values (1, 1, 'Beverages')
insert dbo.Category values (2, 1, 'Soft Drink')
insert dbo.Category values (3, 1, 'Alcohol')
```

This way you can create as many levels of category as you want. Any category where ParentCategoryID = CategoryID is a top level category.

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: You could equally use `NULL` in to `ParentCategoryID` represent a main category. It's personal preference, but I think it makes it more obvious  that it is a top level category than having to compare it to the `CategoryID`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I will look in to this technique to see if i can manage my requirements using this. :) @Rhys

Answer (score -1):

In order to add a new sub category, you should add the category to the table "ItemSubCategory1" after that you can easily add it to the "Drinks" table.

For Example:
If there is a new category name "Hot Drinks" and a new item "Coffee" which comes in Beverages main category (let CatId=1, MainCatText='Beverages' in ItemMainCategory table) then

```
INSERT INTO ItemSubCategory1(CatId,SubCatText) VALUES(4,'Hot Drinks')

INSERT INTO Drinks(ItemId,ItemName,ItemMainCategory,ItemSubCategory)
VALUES(5,'Coffee',1,4)
```