# Storing hierarchical data in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hierarchy

I need to store hierarchical data retrieved from an XML file into a relational database (SQL Server).The data has the following structure in the XML:

**Item**

- ItemId (unique identifier)
- ItemName
- Other fields describing an item

**Item Relationships**

- ParentItemId
- ChildItemId
- RelationshipType (domain-specific informations that describes the relationship)
- Other domain specific fields that describe the relationship

I want to store this data in the DB such that it will be fast and simple to query. As updates to the relationships won't happen often, I'm not too concerned about update/insert/delete performance.

I had considered hierarchyid approach. However there are additional fields associated with a relationship besides the parent and child id (i.e. RelatiopnshipType and a few others) so this doesn't seem feasible.

How about having two tables named Items and ItemRelationships?

- The Items table has columns ItemId (the primary key) and ItemName.
- The ItemRelationships has columns ParentItemId, ChildItemId, RelationshipType.

ParentItemId and ChildItemId are foreign keys of Items.ItemId column. Is this an efficient structure for querying? Bare in mind that a ParentItemId can have multiple ChildItemId's. The depth of the hierarchy could be over 10 levels. 
I'm also confused as to whether this approach is referred to as adjacency list or bridge table or some other term?

Comment: For SQL2008+, I would use [HIERARCHYID (nested sets) data type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28780744/924077).

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086236/designing-hierarchy-tables/

Comment: Why don't you want to use an adjacency list?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean If using hierarchyid or nested sets where would the RelationshipType field be stored? This is a field associated with each parent-child relationship.

Comment: @RogerSmyth: It depends. First, tell me if for a `HIERARCHYID` node/value, all direct parent -> child relationships have the same type ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean no they may not have the same RelationshipType.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated my question with a possible approach. Have one table to store the items and another to store the item relationships. The latter table has columns (ParentItemId, ChildItemId, RelationshipType). I don't know if this approach is known as adjacency list as the relations are in a separate table. Also I am not sure if this is the best design for querying the data. I would prefer HIERARCHYID approach if possible as it is supposed to be simpler for querying.

Comment: I would only add the second table if your children have multiple parents. Otherwise add the relationship describing fields from the childs perspective (e.g. ParentRelationshipType). If you only need to go up or down one level you might consider to add ParentItemID instead of an HirarchyId column.

Comment: @RogerSmyth: In this case I suggest to test next solution: on every level of HIERARCHY node, the label can be an integer (usually) value or decimal value. In last case, you could use decimal places to store relationship type. Example: `DECLARE @n HIERARCHYID = '/11.1/2.5/4/'`. In this case, relationship type between `11` and `2` is `1` and relationship type between `2` and `4` is `5`. It's just a proposal and isn't tested. Could you tell me what will be typical queries that involve relationship type values (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT) ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean That's an interesting idea. I wasn't aware it was possible to do it this way. The typical queries will be SELECT. Thanks.